# Scala Prohibit allocation of value classes

Tags: scala, value-class

According to the documentation on value classes, they may be allocated under a number of circumstances:

> Allocation Summary
>
> a value class is treated as another type.
>
> a value class is assigned to an array.
>
> doing runtime type tests, such as pattern matching.

Is there anyway to say,throw a compilation error if these circumstances occur?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on *why* you want to do that?

Comment: The whole motivation behind value classes is they disappear at run time. No memory allocation, but if I cant control that, the motivation goes away. (Im creating a type safe Json approach without having to actually wrap each value type in a Json type, say like argonaut does)

Comment: Why do you need compile time warnings then? You know precisely when you're making an allocation.

Comment: Are you familiar with Value Classes? http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html 
The compiler does the allocation

Comment: The motivation for value objects isn't to completely eliminate object allocations, but to minimize them - just like the types `Int`, `Long`, and so on, are represented as primitives whenever possible, but get silently boxed/unboxed as necessary. Besides, if your goal is to optimize the performance/memory usage profile of your library, you will need to do some serious profiling to find the real bottlenecks anyway - so this sort of concern smells like premature optimization to me.

Comment: Have you read the introduction to the SIP?  It is exactly the motivation.

Comment: And then to obscure varification of motivation Im finding a bit odd

Comment: @JPullar Yes, I am well aware of what value classes are. Perhaps you didn't understand my question. If you know exactly when such a class causes an actual allocation of an object, you can avoid it without the help of the compiler by remembering when such an allocation occurs.

Comment: @JPullar Or are you afriad of other developers making that "mistake"?

Comment: Yes, bang on, definitely stopping other developers making that mistake.  Despite the clear definition I also find Im getting allocations where I didn't expect them.  It would be nice if the compiler could assist in ironing these out.

Comment: I guess, Im not always sure when I might be performing a runtime type test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built-in (AFAIK).

You could write an SBT plugin which inspects the `.class` files after `compile` task finishes (using a library like BCEL, ASM, etc.) and fails if it finds any value class constructor calls.

Alternately, you should be able to do the same with a [compiler plugin](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/140) (unfortunately, documentation I was able to find is quite old) with a little more difficulty.

Comment: It might be possible to check in the posterasure compiler stage the resulting state of the elimErasedValueType. Perhaps check for an annotation on the value class?

Comment: Actually, more likely earlier, in the TypeAdaptingTransformer, box method